# How to stack 2x4 table legs?

Tags: wood, table

I have a desk made with 2x4 legs I want to increase the height for a work table. I'm thinking adding 5 1/2". How to I connect the new piece onto the original leg?
I've been looking at pocket holes but didn't know if this would be strong with the wood grain.

Comment: How strong does the desk need to be? What's its load? Is it dynamic (e.g. do you break dance on it)?

Comment: As an alternative, how difficult would it be to just replace the legs with longer ones? 2x4s aren't exactly expensive; how much do you think your time and effort is worth?

Comment: +1 for just replacing the legs. Anything built with ordinary 2x4s for legs is not likely to be using any sort of sophisticated joinery that would make replacement a big job.

Comment: you don't even have to replace them. Cut a new 2x4 to the length you want, prop the table up, and fasten the new leg to the existing one.

Comment: If you're worried about appearance, you could taper one side of the existing leg so its profile flies smoothly into the added leg you've mounted alongside it. If you really insist on joining them end to end rather than side by side, plan on a long scarf joint to make the connection strong enough.

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful if you could add a picture of your desk to your question. The commenters are correct. A work table with 2x4 legs is probably not fancy, and doesn't need a fancy job to raise it. If it were my project, I would either replace the legs with longer ones, or add a 5-1/2" stub under the leg while scabbing a full length 2x4 leg to the inside of the original leg. Use 2-1/2 inch screws and horizontally screw the new leg into both the old leg and the stub. You can optionally toe screw from the original leg into the stub - just like a pocket hole, but less of a process.